# Echo $variable$counter in a "for" loop BASH

Tags: bash, ubuntu

```
n=1
test=1000
test1=aaa
```

I'm trying:

```
echo $test$n
```

to get

```
aaa
```

But I get

```
10001
```

I'm trying to use it that way because I have variables: lignePortTCP1,lignePortTCP2,lignePortTCP1, ETC in a for loop like this:

```
declare -i cpt3
cpt3=0
for ((i = 1; i <= cpt; i++)); do
    cpt3=cpt3+1
    echo "Port/Protocole : $lignePortTCP$cpt3 - Nom du Service : $ligneServiceTCP$cpt3"
done
```

Comment: and what are you asking exactly?

Comment: So when I do echo $test$n I get 10001 and I'm trying to get 999

*Sorry I forgot to add the "test1" variable in my post

Answer (score 3):

Given the assigned variables

```
n=1
test1=aaa
```

...and you want to print `aaa` given the values of `test` and `n`, then put the name you want to expand in its own variable, and expand that with the `!` operator, like so:

```
varname="test$n"
echo "${!varname}"
```

This is explicitly discussed in [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

---

That said, variable indirection is not a particularly good practice -- usually, you can do better using arrays, whether associative or otherwise.

For instance:

```
test=( aaa bbb ccc )
n=0
echo "${test[n]}"
```

...for values not starting at 0:

```
test=( [1]=aaa [2]=bbb [3]=ccc )
n=1
echo "${test[n]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to subtract the values of test and n, wrap the computation in $(( ... )) and use
the - operator:

```
$((test-n))
```

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean, I just gave really bad examples for my variable. All I'm trying to accomplish is to get the value of test1 but when I echo $test$n it gives me the value of test + the value of n which becomes 10001 instead of aaa

Answer (score 0):

You could also use eval, though it's probably not better than the technique provided by Charles Duffy.

```
$ n=1
$ test=1000
$ test1=aaa
$ eval echo \${test$n}
aaa
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use `${!}`, but you have to store the combined name in its own variable for that to work:

```
var=test$n
echo "${!var}"
```

If you have control over how the variables get assigned in the first place, it would be better to use an array. Instead of `lignePortTCP1`, `lignePortTCP2`, etc., you would assign the values to `lignePortTCP[0]`, `lignePortTCP[1]`, etc. and then retrieve them with `${lignePort[$n]}`.